# Swipe To Delete in a RecycleView

Tags: android

I'am trying to implement a swipe to delete so I can delete an item from my project but it doesn't show in the application could someone help me, this is the code that I added to my historyFragment

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int i) {
                int position = target.getAdapterPosition();
                mData.remove(position);
                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(NewsRecyclerview);
```

Comment: "but it doesn't show in the application" I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @m0skit0 I can't swipe up to delete an item

Comment: items are moving ? or nothing changes ?

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi nothing changes , should I add sth ?

Comment: couldnt find out exactly, can you try to remove getMovementFlags override method and try again? As far as I understand it blocks the movement

Comment: yess you are riiight thaank you so so much @ErenTüfekçi

Comment: :) will write as answer, please check it

Comment: out of issue! You must avoid using notifyDataSetChanged() as much as you can. notifyItemRemoved(position) is more healthy.

Comment: yees you are riight thank you agaain @ErenTüfekçi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to remove getMovementFlags override method and try again? As far as I understand it blocks the movement